# slicing error in numpy array

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, matplotlib, signal-processing

I am trying to run the following code

```
fs = 1000
data = np.loadtxt("trainingdataset.txt", delimiter=",")
data1 = data[:,2]
data2 = data1.astype(int)
X,Y = data2['521']
```

but it gets me the following error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\hadeer.elziaat\Desktop\testspec.py", line 58, in <module>
    X,Y = data2['521']
IndexError: only integers, slices (`:`), ellipsis (`...`), numpy.newaxis (`None`) and integer or boolean arrays are valid indices
```

my dataset

```
1,4,6,10
2,100,125,10
3,100,7216,254
4,100,527,263
5,100,954,13
6,100,954,23
```

Comment: There is more wrong about your code than just the string-type index. `data[:, 2]` will give you the 3rd column. No way you can unpack that to two variables with `X,Y = data2[521]`.

Comment: What exactly do you want to do? Retrieve the 522th row of the data file? And which columns?

Comment: i want all the data in the third column

Comment: Please, which is the meaning of the ***string*** 521 in your context?

Comment: i wrote it without quotations

Comment: `data2[521]` is a single value. So you need `X = data2[521]` (No `Y` here!!).

Comment: thank u.. but how to take all data from the third column

Comment: _"how to take all data from the third column?"_  the array `data1` contains all the data from the 3rd column, and `data2` contains the same numbers but converted to integers.  — You access a SINGLE element at a specific position like `X = data2[N]`, if you need a number of _consecutive_ values from `data2` you could proceed like this `X1, X2, ..., XM = data2[N:N+M]`  (note that using different names for what are the elements of a sequence is, out of doubt, a bad practice).

Answer (score 0):

You're using the string `'521'` rather than the number `521` for indexing. Try `X,Y = data2[521]` instead.

If you are only given the string, you could cast it to an int first: `X,Y = data2[int('521')]`, but this might result in some errors and/or unexpected behaviour.

Next problem, you are requiring two variable, one for `X` and one for `Y`, yet the `data2[521]` selection only provides you with a single variable (the number in the 3rd column, 522nd row).

Comment: i tried it without quotation but it gives me the following error       
 Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\hadeer.elziaat\Desktop\testspec.py", line 57, in <module>
    X,Y = data1[521]
TypeError: 'numpy.int32' object is not iterable

Answer (score 0):

You say you want all the data in the 3rd column.

I assume you also want some kind of x-axis, since you are attempting to do `X, Y = ...`. How about using the first column for that? Then your code would be:

```
import numpy as np

data = np.loadtxt("trainingdataset.txt", delimiter=',', dtype='int')
x = data[:, 0]
y = data[:, 2]
```

What remains unclear from your question is why you tried to index your `data` with `521` - which failed because you cannot use strings as indices on plain arrays.